# svn:external in git

Tags: svn, git

A little background:

I have a project that used to be in an SVN repository, that had an svn:external folder from outside of the project tree. This external folder is very essential and is required to build the project.

Problem:
Recently, I've decided to move to git, and the only thing that really bugs me now is how to still be able to "embed" this SVN tree in my git repository (It is not up to me whether it moves to git or not(most probably), yet I do commit to it).

I would like to have the minimum (optimally none) setup steps at each location I clone the repository at (prefably all the setup on the git-hosting server). Also it would be superb if git-pull updated the "external" content and git-push pushed changes to the SVN repository.

Example:
Git repo:

- a_folder
- another_folder (root of svn repo)

  - my_file
  - my_other_file

Svn repo:

- my_file
- my_other_file

Answer (score 2):

You don't. Git doesn't have the idea of multiple repos built in. There are external tools like [repo](http://source.android.com/source/version-control.html) and [mr](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mr), although repo doesn't do svn. I've got some SVN repos that use externals and the solution I'm leaning towards right now is mr.